# Using find_if with vector object

Tags: c++11

this code always returns false 
I tried to pass lambda parameter by reference and I had the same result
any tip please

```
vector<int> v1;
v1.push_back(1);
v1.push_back(2);
v1.push_back(3);
v1.push_back(5);

for (int x : v1)
{
    auto it = find_if(v1.begin(), v1.end(), [x](int y){ return x == y; });
    if (it != v1.end())
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Why you expect it to be true? Use debugger

Comment: Think a little bit about what you're doing here. In the first iteration `x` will be equal to `1`, which will be found. Then the next iteration `x` will be `2` which will *also* be found. And so on. All values in the vector will be found, because they are in the vector. And if a value is found you will return `false`. Are you checking for duplicates? Then you need to rethink your algorithm.

Comment: yes I'm checking for duplicates 
would you please help me with this it's the first time I use this function

Comment: @AlaaKhabbaz If you're trying to maintain a collection of items with no duplicates, you could use [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To *check* for duplicates (not remove them, just check for them) then you can do something like this:

Get the first value, and check for it in the ***rest*** of the container. You should not check the first element again because that's the element we are checking currently.

If a duplicate is not found then go on to the second element, and check from the *third* element forward. WE don't need to check the first element because that was done in the previous step.

Then continue like that for all elements.

If you *find* a duplicate then stop the searching and return `true`. If none are found then continue until the end, and then return `false`.

This can be done easily using iterators:

```
// Outer loop, current element to check
for (auto const i = v1.begin(); i != v1.end(); ++i)
{
    // Inner loop, the element to check against
    for (auto const j = i + 1; j != v1.end(); ++j)
    {
        if (*i == *j)
            return true;  // Duplicate found
    }
}

// No duplicates found
return false;
```

The above code shows the principle, you could of course use `std::find_if` instead of the inner loop. The important thing is to start looking at the *next* element. All the previous have already been checked, and you should not compare the current value with itself.

Answer (score 1):

1. Look at your condition in the `if`. What you meant it to do and what it actually does?
2. From using `for` it looks like you want it to go over all the container. Can you find a case where the body of the loop **doesn't** return immediately on the first iteration?